# Minimal Browser for Jupyter

Tags: browser, jupyter

on the Jupiter Project Homepage(http://jupyter.org) there is a screenshot of a very minimal Browser running Jupyter. Does anyone know how this is achieved? It reminds me of Mathematica notebooks and I like it for there is no unnecessary browser address bar etc. This would be extremely helpful on my laptop. I tried the qtconsole but it lacks the web-based interface.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're on a mac have you tried the app Pineapple?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I just saw it now. Yes I have seen the app. I do not like the big toolbar as I do not really need it.